# insert multiple rows with one query using a C# array

Tags: c#, t-sql, bulkinsert, sql-insert

I have a list of `userIds`

`List<int> userIds = new List<int>();`

I have code to insert them in to db.
`ExecuteSQL(sql)` is my own function that abstracts out all the db specific logic

```
string iSql = "";
foreach(int id in userIds){

 iSql = "insert into users (id) values (" + id + ")";
 ExecuteSQL(iSql);

}
```

I want to insert all of these in one query, without having to call a loop like above,
is this possible in SQL?

If so, what would the `string iSql` look like?

I found [Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query),

but that may create a large string.

Other articles i found were either other languages or just confusing as i couldn't relate them to my problem

(i can take care of parameterization later, i just need the query)

Comment: As you got in some answers you can insert up to I think 1000  using the values (1), (2).  If more than 1000 then can use TVP.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Comment: Reference  http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(int id in userIds){
     sb.AppendLine("insert into users (id) values (" + id.ToString() + ");");
}
ExecuteSQL(sb.ToString());
```

You really should be using parameterized queries. But the above will do what you need.

or alternatively.

```
string iSql = string.Format("insert into users (id) values {0};", string.Join(",", userIds.Select(i => string.Format("({0})", i))));
ExecuteSQL(iSql);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at this thread :
[How should I multiple insert multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972974/how-should-i-multiple-insert-multiple-records)

There is a nice way to do what you want.

If you still want to use a string as query you can do something like :

```
    string iSql = "insert into users (id) values";
foreach(int id in userIds){
 iSql += "(" + id + "),";

}
 ExecuteSQL(iSql);
```

but honestly, I don't like it :)

Edit :
Eoldre answer with the StringBuilder is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a stored procedure and send your inserted data(userid) with a xml string. In the stored procedure you can use single insert/select query and inserted all data in table. Please use following code

```
 create proc insertuser
  @xml  xml
  as

 set @xml=N'<ids>
 <user><id>127531</id></user>  
 <user><id>5445</id> </user> 
<user><id>477</id>  </user>
<user><id>785</id>  </user>
<user><id>456</id> </user>
</ids>'                                    
declare @tbl table(id int)

insert into users(id)
select r.c.value('id[1]','int') 
from @xml.nodes('ids/user') as r(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you use this as an answer
I use TVP  to load up to 1 million rows and it is fast
It basically works like a reverse DataReader

As you got in some answers you can insert up to I think 1000 using the values (1), (2). If more than 1000 then can use TVP.

[TVP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

If it is a collection (not a DataTable) then use

[SqlDataRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467431/table-valued-parameter-sending-data-in-small-chunks/12468098#12468098)